# Advanced search only country united states

Tags: advanced-search

I am trying to do an advanced search but in country only United States appears. I have records with different countries. Thanks

[image: search country]

Answer (score 1):

Go to: Administer > Configure > Global Settings > Localization and leave the country field blank on the right for it to show them all https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-civicrm-community/localising-civicrm/

[image]

Comment: It is already modified, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Go to: Administer > Configure > Global Settings > Localization and make sure you have other countries selected in "Available Countries"